# grep /etc/resolv.conf no such file or directory

Tags: networking, apt, recovery-mode

My system is broken, and I'm trying to reinstall the kernel packages in recovery mode with apt in a root shell.

I'm going to need network access. But it seems, my resolv.conf is gone

```
grep /etc/resolv.conf no such file or directory
```

this message keeps popping up.

If I do `dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` it first asks me to create the link, then reboot.
After that, there is still no resolv conf.
after a reboot when i enter recovery mode again, there is still no resolv.conf.

I manually did `resolvconf -u` and the link is there - but i still get that message.

Comment: What steps are you taking to enable networking once you boot into recovery mode?

Comment: i tried the "enable networking" option from the menu selection of the recover screen.

Comment: ok - i fixxed the problem by 1. booting with a live CD, 2. chrooting into the broken system 3. copying the host systems resolv.conf manually